# Awk adding corresponding rows in different columns

Tags: awk

I have a file called presidents.txt. The content inside is as follows...

```
First  Last  Age  Years
Geogre W     57   8.0
John   A     61   4.0
Thomas J     57   8.0
James  M     57   8.0
Andrew J     61   8.0
```

What I need is a program that will add the age and years for each president. For example, George W would be 57+8.0, John A would be 61+4.0, and so on. After adding the numbers for each president, the program would then output the name of the president with the highest number. For example, output here should be "Andrew J at 69". So far I can do this for each president, one at a time, but I would like this to be done in a loop using awk. The command I've been using so far has been

```
awk 'NR==2 {print $3+$4}' presidents.txt
```

This will add the numbers 61 and 4.0, resulting in an output of 65, which I suppose is a start. I'm sure I need to use a loop and arrays but have no idea where to start as I do not have much experience with Unix or coding in general. Any help is appreicated.

Comment: If 2 or more people have the same result of $3+$4 (e.g. see the modified sample input I added to [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/699602/133219)) do you want the first or last or both names or something else printed? Please [edit] your question to include that case in the input and add the exact expected output given your sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming when there are duplicate results of $3+$4 you only want the last such occurrence from the input printed:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR>1 {
    curYear = $3 + $4
    if ( curYear >= maxYear ) {
        maxName = $1 OFS $2
        maxYear = curYear
    }
}
END {
    print maxName, "at", maxYear
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Andrew J at 69
```

For example, given this modified input file where 2 people (`Andrew J` and `Sheila E`) now both have a total $3+$4 value of 69:

```
$ cat file
First  Last  Age  Years
Geogre W     57   8.0
John   A     61   4.0
Thomas J     57   8.0
James  M     57   8.0
Andrew J     61   8.0
Sheila E     65   4.0
```

With the above script we get the last one output:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Sheila E at 69
```

whereas maybe you wanted the first:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR>1 {
    curYear = $3 + $4
    if ( curYear > maxYear ) {
        maxName = $1 OFS $2
        maxYear = curYear
    }
}
END {
    print maxName, "at", maxYear
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Andrew J at 69
```

or all of them:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR>1 {
    curYear = $3 + $4
    if ( curYear >= maxYear ) {
        if ( curYear > maxYear ) {
            numNames = 0
        }
        maxNames[++numNames] = $1 OFS $2
        maxYear = curYear
    }
}
END {
    for ( nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++ ) {
        print maxNames[nameNr], "at", maxYear
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Andrew J at 69
Sheila E at 69
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need for any loop or array to do this job. Try:

```
awk '
            { name= $1 OFS $2 OFS "at" OFS }
NR>1        { age=$3+$4 }
age>ageMax  { ageMax=age; data=name; next }
age==ageMax { data= data ageMax ORS name }
END{ print data ageMax }' infile
```

- Record the First &Last name part with `{ name= $1 OFS $2 OFS "at" OFS }` for future processing.
- Skip the header line and add "Age" to the "Years" with `NR>1{ age=$3+$4 }`.
- If "age" value was grether than "ageMax" then update the value of the "ageMax" with the "age" value and update the "data" from the "name" with `age>ageMax { ageMax=age; data=name; next }`; the `next` statement tells awk to skip proccessing the rest of the codes for the current line and awk will read the next line for processing.
- If we found equal maximum ageMax values, then keep all of them by appending to the "data" value with `age==ageMax { data= data ageMax ORS name }`. If you don't want all, just remove this part of the code and then it will return the very first record with highest ageMax then or replace `age>ageMax` with `age>=ageMax` to return the very last record with highest ageMax instead.
- At the `END{ print data ageMax }`, we print the result.

Answer (score 0):

Combining `awk` and `sort`:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,"at",$3+$4}' file | sort -k4nr | head -1
Andrew J at 69
```

We create a middle file with the sum of age and years as the last field, and then `sort` it using as `k`ey the last, `4`th field, `n`umeric and `r`everse, finally print just the first line with `head`.

---

Here is an improvement to cover the case of more than one lines having the maximum years. We print them all:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,"at",$3+$4}' file | sort -k4nr | uniq -f3 --group | sed '/^$/q'
```

`uniq` is grouping the repeated lines (ignoring the first `3` `f`ields, that means testing only the last number), separating the groups with a blank line, and `sed` is printing only the first group, `q`uiting at first blank line.